# Pro Fit® Ergo Vertical Wireless Trackball: Trackball moving in opposite direction

Tags: windows-10, mouse

When I went to bed my Pro Fit® Ergo Vertical Wireless Trackball (via bluetooth) was moving as expected. When I woke up, my trackball was moving in the opposite direction.

I have tried:

- rebooting
- deleting device and driver from device manager
- deleted device from bluetooth
- re-paired bluetooth device
- reinstall software
- Windows update
- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID{00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_Dev_VID&02047d_PID&8069_REV&0001_fa87847c4f2c&Col01\9&16f83ad&0&0000\Device Parameters

  - `FlipFlopHScroll=1`

I am running Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

In this very specific case, it appears to have been a software corruption of some sort.

I restored an earlier image of Windows and the trackball mouse is working normally again.

Answer (score -1):

If you had anything like a power-surge at night, this might have caused
a hardware problem, requiring that the mouse be replaced.

It might also be a bit of dirt that was introduced into the sensor
and is causing bad readings. Fixing it will require opening up
the mouse.

I don't own such a device, so this is a description found at
[this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Trackballs/comments/uaz7du/kensington_pro_fit_ergo_vertical_users_is_your/)
by the user thecyclops13:

> 1. 3 of the 4 bottom rubber pads have a screw beneath them, the biggest one did not have a screw beneath
> 2. The screw are some odd triangle shape but you can use a tiny flat head and it works
> 3. Top cover is glued, took me a while to figure out. Its the one with LED's and trackball, just carefully pry it open
> 4. Once inside, there are 3 black Philips head screws holding the button and scroll wheel assembly
> 5. Beneath that circuit board, you will see the scroll wheel assembly in a white holder, carefully pry it out and clean it, mine had some
>    gunk on it, I also lubed with a dab of silicon oil
> 6. Be careful or take a picture of the assembly before you open it, the above step will take some care to put it back together
> 7. That's it, the scroll is working fine now!

Going to that length might not be required, if you can clean out
the dirt at an earlier step.

Comment: thanks for the tips. I just went cycling the mouse's power for a fifth time and all of the sudden things work as expected again.

Comment: So this was probably the result of a power-surge. If electricity in your environment is unstable, you might require an UPS or at least a surge-protector.

Comment: Actually, turning on a device causes a mini power-surge. If this is the cause, it might happen again (but you now know what to do).

Comment: Now, who downvoted and why ?

Comment: Wasn't me. Your response was a distinct possibility.